# Running pyspark in (Anaconda - Spyder) in windows OS

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

Dears, 
I am using windows 10 and I am familiar with testing my python code in Spyder.
however, when I am trying to write ïmport pyspark" command, Spyder showing "No module named 'pyspark'"
Pyspark is installed in my PC and also I can do import pyspark in command prompt without any error.
I found many blogs explaining how to do this in Ubuntu but I did not find how to solve it in windows.

Comment: Why are you using `import spyder`? Also, Ubinto do you mean Ubuntu?

Comment: When you are running import spyder. then how are you getting No module named pyspark error. statement is contradicting here. Share your exact command and error screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the command I write is "import pyspark" and the exact error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'" and yes what I mean is Ubuntu

Comment: @MohammadRasheed: Edit your question properly with correct description.

Comment: Set your pythonpath  enviornment variable as pyspark isn't probably at your pythonpath variable. Go to location where pyspark folder is located and add that folder to your class path.

Comment: in environment variable I have PYSPARK_PYTHON = C:\Users\current\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: but I have spark located in c:\spark shall I add folder inside spark called python and re-install python than change environment variable ? is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Well for using packages in Spyder, you have to install them through Anaconda. You can open 
"anaconda prompt" and the write down the blew code:

```
conda install pyshark
```

That will give you the package available in SPYDER.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I have installed Pyspark in windows 10 few weeks back. Let me tell you how I did it.
I followed "https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/".

So after following each step precisely you can able to run pyspark using either command promp or saving a python file and running.

When you run via notebook(download Anaconda). start anacoda shell and type pyspark. now you don't need to do "ïmport pyspark".
run your program without this and it will be alright. you can also do spark-submit but for that I figured out that you need to remove the PYSPARK_DRIVER_PATH and OPTS PATH in environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have followed the same steps, it works in jupyter but still I cannot run spark in spyder